# group diferent results by country in array

Tags: php, foreach

i have an array and i need to group the results by country. Ill post what i have and what i need. Keep in mind that the name of the country come from database and are not static. I'm stuck in a foreach and i'll post it bellow. I think im failling while pushing the items inside the array i think. Any tips on how to solve this?

***WHAT I HAVE***

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [RECRUETE] => 2020
                [NMBER_RETE] => 25
                [CAT] => SERRALHEIRO
                [TITU] => 2 YEARS
                [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => holand
            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [RECRUETE] => 2021
            [NMBER_RETE] => 12
            [CAT] => SEtryu
            [TITU] => 22 YEARS
            [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => portugal
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [RECRUETE] => 2022
            [NMBER_RETE] => 32
            [CAT] => SEreIRO
            [TITU] => 21 YEARS
            [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => holand
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [RECRUETE] => 2021
            [NMBER_RETE] => 325
            [CAT] => TRUIO
            [TITU] => 1 YEARS
            [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => portugal
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [RECRUETE] => 2020
            [NMBER_RETE] => 25
            [CAT] => SERRALHEIRO
            [TITU] => 2 YEARS
            [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => portugal
        )
)
```

***WHAT I NEED***

```
 Array
(
    [portugal] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [RECRUETE] => 2021
                            [NMBER_RETE] => 12
                            [CAT] => SEtryu
                            [TITU] => 22 YEARS
                            [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => portugal
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [RECRUETE] => 2021
                            [NMBER_RETE] => 12
                            [CAT] => SEtryu
                            [TITU] => 22 YEARS
                            [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => portugal
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [RECRUETE] => 2021
                        [NMBER_RETE] => 325
                        [CAT] => TRUIO
                        [TITU] => 1 YEARS
                        [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => portugal
                )
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [RECRUETE] => 2020
                        [NMBER_RETE] => 25
                        [CAT] => SERRALHEIRO
                        [TITU] => 2 YEARS
                        [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => portugal
                )
            )
[holand] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [RECRUETE] => 2022
                        [NMBER_RETE] => 32
                        [CAT] => SEreIRO
                        [TITU] => 21 YEARS
                        [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => holand
                )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [RECRUETE] => 2020
                        [NMBER_RETE] => 25
                        [CAT] => SERRALHEIRO
                        [TITU] => 2 YEARS
                        [GRUPO_ANUNCIO] => holand
                    )
            )
    )
```

```html
        $country_array = array();
        foreach ($results as $k=> $result)
        {
            $country = $result['GRUPO_ANUNCIO'];
            if (in_array($country, $country_array) )
            {
                array_push($contry_array[$country], $result);
            }else{
                $country_array[]= $result['GRUPO_ANUNCIO'];
                array_push($country_array[$result['GRUPO_ANUNCIO']], $result);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh well i was over complicating it. I got it by doing:

```
$country_array = array();
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $country_array[$result['GRUPO_ANUNCIO']][] = $result;
}
```